# HTTP Basic Auth with Golang

Tags: http, authentication, go, basic-authentication

How do I implement basic auth with a Golang site? So that when someone visits a page they will be prompted by their **browser** with a login.

Comment: https://github.com/goji/httpauth will allow you to set a user/pass and prompt. Note that basic auth is in plain text when not over HTTPS, and is not especially secure.

Comment: The simplest way https://github.com/stokito/go-http-server-basic-auth which works with net.Server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to force a user to authenticate/make that basic auth prompt in the users browser appear you send the header `WWW-Authenticate : Basic ream="mydomain"`

So if you have a `http.ResponseWriter` called `w`, you can do

```
 w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="mydomain"`)
```

Which will cause the browser to open the prompt you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Echo's labstack project](https://echo.labstack.com/), which provides Basic Auth middleware:

```
e.Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func(username, password string, c echo.Context) (bool, error) {
    // check username and password for a match here
}))
```

Use the code above to protect any route groups with basic authentication.