# Basic Authentication for static resources

Tags: http, authentication, go, basic-authentication, gorilla

How can I add basic authentication to my static resources? With the code below, I'm able to view any files that are in the labels folder. I know in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187853/http-basic-auth-with-golang?rq=1) question it was explained how to do it. But how would would I set the header when a `http.ResponseWriter` is not used?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    port := GetPort()
    log.Println("[-] Listening on...", port)

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/labels/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/labels/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./labels/"))))

    err := http.ListenAndServe(port, r)
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// GetPort is for herkou deployment
func GetPort() string {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "4747"
        log.Println("[-] No PORT environment variable detected. Setting to ", port)
    }
    return ":" + port
}
```

Comment: Wrap your handler by a authentication middleware to allow your every request to pass through the authentication middleware.

Comment: Why not serve the pdf files from the handler in which the user can hit the endpoint for a pdf file and then you can use http to download the file after validation. your current approach is not good since you are serving all static files and want validation on them. So it is better just to apply validation on pdf file which can be downloaded using a link on your page.

Comment: @Himanshu that sounds like a good idea. Sorry I'm new to go, so I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: It is ok just follow the process I have provided in my answer. Serve the static files like html, css, js normally and then provide a url on which you should create a handler just like I did and then add authentication for the user to pass before downloading the file. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Create a wrapper around each handler to pass the request from the authentication middleware which will forward the request further after authentication is done else return the response with error as

```
func authentication(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Executing authentication")
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}

// open the dialog to download pdf files.
func dowloadPdf(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YOUR_FILE")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    w.Write([]byte("File downloaded"))
}

func main(){
     pdfHandler := http.HandlerFunc(dowloadPdf)
     http.Handle("/servepdf", authentication(pdfHandler))
     http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

But if I consider the fact there is no need to have authentication when serving static files like html, css, js etc. It would be better to create a handler to serve pdf files after authenticating users.

You can also use [negorni](https://github.com/urfave/negroni) middlewares with gorilla mux rather than creating custom middlewares.

Comment: I don't see how this works in my existing code. Also, I have pdf files that need to have basic authentication applied to them.

Comment: @TylerZika just use the middleware with your gorilla mux router.

Comment: @TylerZika I have updated my answer. One more thing you can do is you use negroni middleware with gorilla mux instead of custom just like I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    port := GetPort()
    log.Println("[-] Listening on...", port)

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/labels/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/labels/", ServeLabels(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./labels/")))))

    err := http.ListenAndServe(port, r)
    log.Fatal(err)
}

func ServeLabels(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="mydomain"`)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

// GetPort is for herkou deployment
func GetPort() string {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "4747"
        log.Println("[-] No PORT environment variable detected. Setting to ", port)
    }
    return ":" + port
}
```

something like this, or you could just go ahead and use the gorilla mux middleware.

Comment: when you visit `http://localhost:4747/labels/` in your web browser, the authentication window appears? That is not happening for me.